# Not able to copy file from other file completely with both files opened in binary mode

Tags: c, file, filestream, fread, printf

I am trying to copy from one   file to another both opened in binary mode

here:

*pdata is the file pointer to the file from which input is to be taken*

*outfile is the file pointer to the file in which data is to be written.*

my input file is around 400mb and after the program executions ends the output file contains only 80mb. Why complete file is not copying?

I know I am leaving some bytes when I am trying to calculate no of packets.

```
int num_RTP_packets=file_Size/(TS_PKT_SIZE * MAX_TS_PKTS); //Total no of Packets

for(int i=0;i<num_RTP_packets;i++)
{  
    long result;

    uint8* m_RTPPacketBuf =(uint8*) malloc(TS_PKT_SIZE * MAX_TS_PKTS); 

    int chunk=TS_PKT_SIZE* MAX_TS_PKTS;

    result=fread (m_RTPPacketBuf,chunk,1,pData); 

    fprintf(out_file,"%s",m_RTPPacketBuf);

    free(m_RTPPacketBuf);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fwrite` in place of `fprintf`.

```
fwrite(m_RTPPacketBuf, chunk, 1,outfile );
```

---

Please consider following suggestions,

1. Move `result` and other declarations outside the loop
2. `chunk` can be replaced by a constant/macro and obviously placing outside loop if constant.
3. `malloc` can be avoided as the memory to be allocated is not varying and instead, array of fixed size can be used.
4. Check for return value of `fread` and `fwrite`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `fprintf()` to write the data. The `%s` indicates a string. I would guess you have a zero byte in the data which terminates the string.

I'd use `fwrite()` instead. (See [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fwrite.htm)).